# How to get the name of the property that is bound to a column in HBM?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created a HBM file. In code I have an actual column name available for me(through a property file). I want to get associated property name of that column to form a HQL. Is there an API that is provided by Hibernate to get the property name that is mapped/bound to a DB column in HBM file?

Answer (score 2):

There is a semi official API for accessing the metadata of classes:

```
Class<?> entityClass = ...;
String columnName = ...;
EntityManager em = ...;
final SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) 
    ((Session) em.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory();
AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(entityClass);
for (String propertyName : persister.getPropertyNames()) {
  for (String propertyColumnName : persister.getPropertyColumnNames(propertyName)) {
    if (columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(propertyColumnName)) {
      return propertyName;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find is this quote from the [version 3.5 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/metamodel.html) stating, that at least in JPA ther ist currently no such  API. But I couldn't find anything newer, so it seems there still isn't such an API.

> As of today the JPA 2 metamodel does not provide any facility for
>   accessing relational information pertaining to the physical model. It
>   is expected this will be addressed in a future release of the
>   specification.

Of course Hibernate must have this information somewhere, at least in the opposite direction, but I don't think they exposing it through an API, which is intended for public use.

You could probably do some hacking by debugging through the hibernate code to see, where they get the information from, when constructing sql statements.